# How to separate comma separated values in a list to make it individual values of a list

Tags: python

I am fetching some switches commands output inside list in python,I am able to get result in list , but that list contains two elements and even those elements are comma separated and i want to get those comma separated values as individual element of list.

I am using netmiko module where i am taking out some command output in list using python.

````
                for k in range(len(cli_commands)):
                    net_connect.send_command(cli_commands[k])
                    vall=net_connect.send_command(cli_commands[k])
                    myList1.append(vall)
              ```print(myList)

Actual result is:

['Cisco IOS Software, C2960S Software (C2960S-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.0(2)SE11, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)', 'NAME: "1", DESCR: "WS-C2960S-24TS-L"\nPID: WS-C2960S-24TS-L  , VID: V02  , SN: FOC1452X5C5\n\n']


Expectation:

['Cisco IOS Software', 'C2960S Software (C2960S-UNIVERSALK9-M)', 'Version 15.0(2)SE11', 'RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)', 'NAME: "1"', 'DESCR: "WS-C2960S-24TS-L"\nPID: WS-C2960S-24TS-L'  ,' VID: V02'  , 'SN: FOC1452X5C5\n\n']

or
['Cisco IOS Software','C2960S Software (C2960S-UNIVERSALK9-M)',Version 15.0(2)SE11','DESCR: "WS-C2960S-24TS-L"\nPID: WS-C2960S-24TS-L','SN: FOC1452X5C5\n\n']
````

Comment: Lookup the `.split()` method for strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to `.split(',')` each string to get a nested list and then make it plain. The use of `.split()` removes extra spaces at the start and end of each sub_string.

```
the_list = ['Cisco IOS Software, C2960S Software (C2960S-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.0(2)SE11, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)', 'NAME: "1", DESCR: "WS-C2960S-24TS-L"\nPID: WS-C2960S-24TS-L  , VID: V02  , SN: FOC1452X5C5\n\n']

the_list = [map(lambda x: x.strip(), item.split(',')) for item in the_list]
new_list = [item for sub_list in the_list for item in sub_list]
```

The first line transforms each string inside `the_list` into a map generator that applies `.strip()` (trimming spaces) to each substring after dividing by the `','` character. The second one is just to make the list plain, this is `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]` will become `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. It is equivalent to:

```
the_list = ['Cisco IOS Software, C2960S Software (C2960S-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.0(2)SE11, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)', 'NAME: "1", DESCR: "WS-C2960S-24TS-L"\nPID: WS-C2960S-24TS-L  , VID: V02  , SN: FOC1452X5C5\n\n']

new_list = []
for string in the_list:
    for item in string.split(','):
        new_list.append(item.strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need `str.split` with `list.extend`

**Ex:**

```
myList1 = []        
for k in range(len(cli_commands)):
    net_connect.send_command(cli_commands[k])
    vall=net_connect.send_command(cli_commands[k])
    myList1.extend(vall.strip().split(","))
print(myList1)
```

Comment: Thanks all for your help, i got my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by  absolutelydevastated is correct but you have to use it like this

```
myList = ['Cisco IOS Software, C2960S Software (C2960S-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.0(2)SE11, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)', 'NAME: "1", DESCR: "WS-C2960S-24TS-L"\nPID: WS-C2960S-24TS-L  , VID: V02  , SN: FOC1452X5C5\n\n']

cs_mylist = []
for y in [x.split(',') for x in myList]:
    for z in y:
        cs_mylist.append(z)

print(cs_mylist)
```