# How to read content of txt file the values are comma separated and add it to a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a file that contains the following content. This is a sample of the file. The fine contains up to 1000 values.

```
'1022409', '10856967', '11665741'
```

I need to read the file and create this list `['1022409', '10856967', '11665741']`

I'm using the following code:

```
with open('Pafos.txt', 'r') as f:
    parcelIds_list = f.readlines()
    print (parcelIds_list[0].split(','))
```

The value is of `parcelIds_list` parameter is this list `["'1022409', '10856967', '11665741'"]` with only index 0.

Any ideas please?

Comment: The code you posted returns the individual strings,`'1022409'`, `'10856967'`. Do you want to remove whitespace and quote marks as well?  Does the file really contain 1000 values in a single line? What do you want to do with this file? You could use eg Pandas to read that file as a single series of 1000 items.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks. Correct, I do not need the quote as well. That's why I accepted other solution than mine. The file contains ids of properties. Thanks for the advice regaring Pandas. I will search it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57051462/1395874).

```
with open('Pafos.txt', 'r') as f:
    parcelIds_list = f.readlines()
    cs_mylist = []
    for y in [x.split(',') for x in parcelIds_list]:
        for z in y:
            cs_mylist.append(z.replace(' ', ''))
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow this code

```
with open ('Pafos.txt', 'r') as f:
  # To split 
  num = f.readline().split(', ')
  # To remove ' and create list
  # If u want list of string
  num_list = [x.replace('\'', '') for x in num]
```

Output

```
['1022409', '10856967', '11665741']
```

If u want list of int

```
# If u want list of int
num_list = [int(x.replace('\'', '')) for x in num]
```

Output

```
[1022409, 10856967, 11665741]
```

If u have more than one row in file, you need to add some extra line of code

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit hard to code with the few lines you have given from the text file, but try this :

```
temp = []
with open('Pafos.txt', 'r') as f:
    parcelIds_list = f.readlines()
    for j in parcelIDS_list:
         temp.extend(j.split(", "))
    new_list = [i.strip()[1:-1] for i in temp]
    print(new_list)
```

Let me know if this doesn't work, and what went wrong. I will modify my answer likewise.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a cleaner way, but this works:

```
with open('Pafos.txt', 'r') as f:
    parcelIds_list = f.readlines()
    line = parcelIds_list[0]
    line = line.replace("'", "")
    line = line.replace(" ", "")
    line = line.split(',')
    print(line)
```